# Intento hacer un push y me aparece otra cuenta

Tags: git, github, git-push, error-403

Yo antes habia agregado otra cuenta a mi pc para hacer un push y estoy intentando hacer un push con la otra cuenta que tenia antes de agregar la otra y me aparece el siguiente error

`remote: Permission to camilo51/Portafolio-Pereira.git denied to cristian-pereira. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/camilo51/Portafolio-Pereira.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

necesito subir el push con camilo51 pero me aparece la de cristian-pereira y ya elimine las credenciales del windows y tambien cambien el user y el email de git pero me sigue apareciendo el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Me sucedió lo mismo hace un par de horas y lo solucioné así:

Elimina tus credenciales de Windows:

1. Abre panel de control
2. Cuentas de usuario
3. Administrar credenciales
4. Credenciales de Windows
5. Elimina todas las que empiecen con `git`

No cierres esa ventana que la vas a utilizar otra vez.

Ve a tu cuenta de Github:

1. Click a tu usuario y `settings`
2. Developer settings
3. Personal access tokens
4. Tokens (Classic)
5. Generate new token
6. Pon una nota para recordar de que es y selecciona todos los campos de `repo`

[image: Repo]

7. Generate new token
8. Te va a regresar a la ventana de `tokens` y te va a mostrar unos números y letras, copialos (**Nota:** Esto es visible una sola vez, si no lo copias aquí tienes que hacerlo otra vez)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego regresas a la ventana de las credenciales de Windows

1. Click en agregar credencial de Windows
2. En password pegas lo que copiaste de `GitHub`
3. En nombre de usuario pones tu correo o nombre de usuario de `GitHub`
4. En la dirección pones `git:https://github.com`
5. Listo ya puedes trabajar normalmente.